# java.lang.NullPointerException and return code

Tags: java, linux, bash, opencv

I'm running some java binary from bash like:

run_me.sh

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Djava.library.path=path1/libs/opencv/lib -jar path2/bin/application.jar
echo "Exit code: "$?
```

but inside application I get `java.lang.NullPointerException`, howewer return code is 0, but I need some non zero exit code to understand from bash that application failed.

What is the proper way to handle such cases?

**Update:**

Here is an exxample of 'nested' try catch blocks, when I throw exception in `inner_package_class` return code is 0. So what is the proper way to get exception from inner_package_class.method1()?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        inner_package_class.method1();
        System.out.printf("After inner method!\n");
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.exit(1); 
    }
}

public class inner_package_class {

    public static void method1() {

        System.out.printf("From inner method!\n");

        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Some exception 2.");
        } catch (Throwable t) {

        }

    }
}
```

**Update 1:**
This work as expected (return non zero exit code).

```
public class inner_package_class {

    public static void method1() throws Exception {
        System.out.printf("From inner method!\n");

        throw new Exception("Some exception 2.");
    }
}
```

Comment: the return code is depending on what the application does, the default is `return 0` here, i don´t know if you could change that one.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the stack trace of that exception.  In particular, whether the exception occurs in the main thread is relevant;  if it doesn’t, you will need to notify the main thread (or whichever thread calls System.exit) of the failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a try-catch-block around your main method and use

```
System.exit(1)
```

when you catch a Throwable

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
     ... // your original code
  } catch (Throwable t) {
     // log the exception 
    t.printStacktrace(); // or use your logging framework 
    System.exit(1); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, as long as the nested catch blocks throw an exception to the outer ones in case of a failure. If they **handle** the exception and continue the program, then the outer catch block is not able to set the return code.

Comment: This will not make a difference.  If the main thread were throwing the NullPointerException, Java would already return a nonzero exit code.

Comment: I have updated my question with example of 'nested' case.

Answer (score 0):

the return code is set by the exit method of System:  by the way if, for instance, You want to return -1 in case of exception you can do as follow: in Your Main class you have to catch all throwable (so you will handle all possible case). here is an example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try { YOUR CODE 
} catch(throwable t){
System.exit(-1);
}
System.exit(0);
}
```

the code show You how return -1 in case of exception and 0 in case of success.